# How Do I Store Integers from File of Mixed Types into an Array? Java

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

I have a text file (Scanner file) with some integers and strings. I want to go through the file, take the integers and store them to an integer array (array1).

Here is the method I am using:

```
  public void printIntArray(Scanner file){
      int x = 0;
      while(file.hasNext()){
        array1[x] = file.nextInt();
        x++;
      }

      System.out.println("The list size is: " + (x+1));
      System.out.print("The list is:");

    for(int z=0; z <= x ; z++)
        System.out.println(array1[z]);

    }
```

And here is my output:

Enter the name of the file: input.txt
The contents of the file are: 12 dsafa 14 daf 11 10 afa 3.5
The list size is: 1
The list is:0

array1[] is declared here:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab2_2Menu {

private static int LENGTH = 100;
private int[] array1;
private String fileName;

public Lab2_2Menu(){

  array1 = new int [LENGTH];

}
```

Comment: where do you declare array1[]?

Comment: maybe try printing the results of nextInt in the while loop

Comment: Maybe you already used the `next()` methods to generate the output (`12 dsafa 14 daf 11 10 afa 3.5`). If you then pass the same `Scanner` object (`file`) to this method, it is still at the end of the file, so you should probably call `reset()` first.

Comment: I thought that's what I'm doing at the end of the method. Do you mean something different?

Comment: @MichelMichaelMeyer I did, good point. However, I just tried implementing file.reset() at the beginning of the while loop. No changes to the output.

Comment: Oh, I just read that `reset()` does not do what I thought it would do. It seems to be better to create a new Scanner on the same file before passing it to the method...does this help?

Comment: Yes, probably passing the File to the method and creating a scanner there might be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using `List<Integer>` instead of an `[]`.  Just iterate through the file and remove all non number characters with a comma, replace all duplicate commas then split on a comma.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("input.txt"));
    printIntArray(scanner);
}

public static void printIntArray(Scanner file) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (file.hasNext()) {
        String[] tokens = file.nextLine().replaceAll("\\D", ",").replaceAll(",+", ",").split(",");
        for (String token : tokens) {
            if(!token.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                list.add(Integer.parseInt(token));                  
            }
        }
    }

    for (Integer num : list) {
        System.out.println(num);
    }

}
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks very much. Could you explain what is happening in the while loop? New at this..

Comment: The while loop grabs each line of the file.  It then replaces all non number characters in the file with a `,`, next it replaces all consecutive commas with a single comma.  Then it splits the string into an array using a comma as a delimiter.  It then iterates through the array of strings and converts all non null strings to an integer and stores then in the `List<Integer>`